# Find nearest number in vector with conditions

Tags: c++, c++11, search, vector

Let's say I have a vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> inputs = {3,2,6,3,7,1,8};
int left = 1; // Number 3
int right = 4; // Numbers 2,6,3,7
int middle = 2; // Numbers 1,8
```

Now for every number in '**middle**' (1, 8), I'd like to find out what's the **nearest** **GREATER** number  in vector 'left side, and right side'. If there is no greater number, return **nearest** **SMALLER** number.

```
// Iterating the last two numbers 1, and 8.
for(int i = left+right; i<left+right+middle; i++){
   ...
}
```

I have tried getting the **nearest** **GREATER element** with the `std::lower_bound`, but it always returns some number. Even if there is no greater or equal element. Therefore I cannot proceed...

The output should look like:

```
closest-left, closest-right --> index in vector

3,2 --> index 0,1
3,7 --> index 0,4
```

Explanation of output:

The number nearest to 1 in the left side {3}, is 3, in the left side {2,6,3,7}, its 2.

The number nearest to 8 in the left side {3}, is 3, in the left side {2,6,3,7}, its 7.

What's the other way to approach this?

Comment: middle = 2. How is middle (1,8)?

Comment: `std::lower_bound` works on sorted ranges.   You're using it on an unsorted range, which is probably why it "doesn't work".

Comment: Unfortunately sorting is not an option. But I would still need to get nearest smallest if !nearestGreater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `min_element` with custom comparer.

```
const std::vector<int> inputs = {3,2,6,3,7,1,8};
int left = 1; // Number 3
int right = 4; // Numbers 2,6,3,7
int middle = 2; // Numbers 1,8

for (int i = left + right; i < left + right + middle; ++i) {
    auto as_tuple = [&, i](int e) { return std::make_tuple(e < inputs[i],
                                                           std::abs(e - inputs[i]));};
    auto comparer = [&, i](int lhs, int rhs){ return as_tuple(lhs) < as_tuple(rhs); };
    auto it1 = std::min_element(inputs.begin(), inputs.begin() + left, comparer);
    auto it2 = std::min_element(inputs.begin() + left,
                                inputs.begin() + left + right,
                                comparer);
    // Assuming non-empty ranges: else check left, right with 0
    std::cout << *it1 << ", " << *it2
              << " --> index "
              << std::distance(inputs.begin(), it1) << ", "
              << std::distance(inputs.begin(), it2) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/shtJmn)